# gitlab CI build script syntax error

Tags: build-script, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to run a build script in Gitlab CI but it complains about a syntax error that I don't understand.

This is the script I have configured in Gitlab:

```
# test syntax of all *.php and *.ctp files
for f in $(find . -name "*.php" -or -name "*.ctp")
do 
    php -l $f
done
```

and this is the output of Gitlab after commit:

```
cd /opt/gitlab-runner/embedded/service/gitlab-runner/tmp/builds/project-1 && git reset --hard && git clean -fdx && git remote set-url origin http://gitlab-ci-token:xxxxxx@git01.peoplefone.com/web/portals.git && git fetch origin
HEAD is now at da5f9b9 test CI 7
From http://git01.peoplefone.com/web/portals
   da5f9b9..559f74b  develop    -> origin/develop
cd /opt/gitlab-runner/embedded/service/gitlab-runner/tmp/builds/project-1 && git reset --hard && git checkout 559f74be65167b67cd7761cb8cbae8bcb528dd40
HEAD is now at da5f9b9 test CI 7
Previous HEAD position was da5f9b9... test CI 7
HEAD is now at 559f74b... test CI 8
# test syntax of all *.php and *.ctp files
for f in $(find . -name "*.php" -or -name "*.ctp")
/tmp/executor20150409-17218-twsoje: line 12: syntax error near unexpected token `echo'
```

as you can see I don't have any 'echo' statement in my script, could anyone help me on that? thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying a bit the following script worked:

```
# test syntax of all *.php and *.ctp files
for file in $(find . -name *.php -or -name *.ctp); do
    php -l $file;
done
```

but I still don't understand the error above..